# Appfog file_get_contents and curl connection timeout

Tags: php, curl, laravel-4, file-get-contents, appfog

I searched for similar issues at SO, but none worked for me.

I deployed my laravel 4 app on appfog and try to get content from an external website.

I've tried several things:

- file_get_contents -> Connection timeout.
- curl -> Connection timeout
- Tried to set a custom timeout.not working

My PHP-Settings:

```
allow_url_fopen On
cURL support enabled
```

Is there something about appfog that you cannot access an external website?

Comment: If you are able to connect to the target service from your local computer or a different server, you might be better off contacting them directly.

Comment: Yes it is working normal on my local system. I sent this issue to the appfog support and waiting for an answer. I thougth there is maybe someone else who had the same problem

Comment: If you get an answer and post it here, that will be helpful for others then

Comment: I just saw that people are complaining about the curl issue on the appfog-community-support for 2 days. It looks like that the problem only appears on EU-AWS serves. I'll keep this thread unsolved till I have clear solution on that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got response from the Appfog Team.

They say that it is a problem with their EU-AWS servers and they're trying to fix this. **It isn't fixed yet.**

**So normaly `file_get_contents` and `curl` should work.**

> Meantime solution for this problem: 
>  Move your app to US-AWS servers. Everything works fine there.